# Adding images with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, image, angularjs

Hi I am new to angular js, the app I am working on uses it. But I have stumbled into a problem... (I mainly do html/css) when adding images to the markup the regular way they dont show up:

```
<img src="image/source/image.png"/>
```

So I did the following to the controller file:

```
  subscriptionControllers.controller('imagesController', function($scope) {
  $scope.image = [{
    src: 'image/source/image.png',
  }];
});
```

then added to the html:

```
<img ng-src="{{image}}"/>
```

But still nothing is showing up.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, thank you!

EDIT:

Yes the image exists, and the path is correct
When I look at the console it shows the image as a:
image.png%22%7D]
/subscription/images

so it is adding %22%7D to the image I don't know why, if I click the image link in the console it takes me to a 404 page.

Edit:
I no longer think this is the problem, when I look at the console and click the images tab, it displays the image as type: html/text I am not sure why it is doing this, any clue?

Comment: There should be no problem with your code in angularjs, are you sure the image exists?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I could see your image model is an array of json object. If so then please do the below changes in the view while accessing the image model.

```
<img ng-src="{{image[0].src}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have specified wrong path in the image src. You can check whether the image is loaded, using firebug or developers tool available in every Browser.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have defined you ng-app and ng-controller, everything looks correct, did a test example here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JnwCyEWT3KiZcsrSg6Ro?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>
    <img ng-src="{{image}}"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
// Code goes here

angular.module("myApp", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.image = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this  `<img src="{{image[index].src}}"/>`

It seems you are using array of objects so in your case "index" is the object index which you want to show .
Hope this will help you.

Comment: This will work, its just not the angular way to do it see @Sai for the best answer.